# Convert nested array of objects to a flat structure using recursion : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of objects with the following structure

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        name: "child1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "granchild1",
            children: [],
            class: "level-2 leaf",
            config: {
              name: "granchild1",
              value1: false,
              value2: false
            }
          }
        ],
        class: "level-1 leaf",
        config: {
          name: "child1",
          value1: false,
          value2: false
        }
      },
      {
        name: "child2",
        children: [],
        class: "level-1 leaf",
        config: {
          name: "child2",
          value1: false,
          value2: false
        }
      }
    ],
    class: "level-0 group",
    config: {
      name: "parent",
      value1: false,
      value2: false
    }
  }
];
```

I need to convert these array of objects into a flat sttructure with just `config` property in it. Can somehelp me how to do this recursively? Help would be much appreciated

Output should look like

```
const result = [
  {
    name: "granchild1",
    value1: false,
    value2: false
  },
  {
    name: "child1",
    value1: false,
    value2: false
  },
  {
    name: "child2",
    value1: false,
    value2: false
  },
  {
    name: "parent",
    value1: false,
    value2: false
  }
];
```

Code that I tried

```
const recur = (arr) => {
  const res = arr.map((item) => {
    let val = item.config;
    if (item.children.length) return recur(item.children);
    return val;
  });
  return res;
};
console.log(recur(arr));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it recursevly with passing the array reference by every recurse

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    name: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        name: "child1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "granchild1",
            children: [],
            class: "level-2 leaf",
            config: {
              name: "granchild1",
              value1: false,
              value2: false
            }
          }
        ],
        class: "level-1 leaf",
        config: {
          name: "child1",
          value1: false,
          value2: false
        }
      },
      {
        name: "child2",
        children: [],
        class: "level-1 leaf",
        config: {
          name: "child2",
          value1: false,
          value2: false
        }
      }
    ],
    class: "level-0 group",
    config: {
      name: "parent",
      value1: false,
      value2: false
    }
  }
];

let collect = (arr, result = []) => {
 
   arr.forEach(prop => {
      result.push({...prop.config})
      collect(prop.children, result)
   })
   return result
}

let result = collect(arr1)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: How can I reverse this? If i store the ids of objects in children's array instead and rest of the objects are in the same flat array as parent